# Comment « bafouiller » a-t-il donné lieu à « bafouille » ?

Tags: étymologie, argot

En argot, une « [bafouille](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bafouille/0) » est une lettre.

L'[étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bafouille/0) de « bafouille » indique que le mot dérive de « bafouiller », ce qui en soit est assez évident, mais je ne vois pas le lien de signification entre les deux.

Pourquoi et comment « bafouille » en est-il venu à désigner une lettre ?

Answer (score 4):

Une *bafouille* désigne une lettre (où l'on bafouille quelques mots à son interlocuteur) comme un *blabla* peut désigner un discours (*... et nous avons écouté son blabla pendant 30 minutes... très intéressant au demeurant*) : en argot, il est courant d'employer des termes péjoratifs même s'il n'y a aucune intention de dévaloriser.

Par ironie et auto-dérision, certainement.

Comment: Ce n'est peut-être pas très clair, mais ma question porte plus sur la relation entre _bafouille_ et _bafouiller_ que sur celle entre _bafouille_ et _lettre_.

Comment: C'est ma réponse qui n'était pas assez claire. J'y ai fait apparaître ce lien: l'usage a voulu que ce soit *une bafouille*, mais ça aurait aussi bien pu être *un bafouillage*. Je ne crois pas que qui que ce soit ait choisi, au final.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothèse : on bafouille quand on est intimidé, en particulier dans les circonstances formelles.  Exactement les mêmes circonstances où on est amené à écrire une lettre.